# Can I install VS 2010 and VS 2010 Express on same machine

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to install and use VS2010 and VS 2010 Express on same machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya i have both VS2010 professional as well as VS2010 Exp installed on my system. And both are functioning normaly.